Scarb.lock and Scarb.toml do not appear in my file within VS code
I'm a beginner in coding, so for some my question may sound very, you know... beginner-like.
I'm trying to make a smart contract for a Starknet basecamp. I have a problem, after installing all the necessary tools, scarb, git etc. I opened VS code to start the Smart Contract but scarb.lock and scarb.toml don't appear. Can someone help me?
I have already installed scarb inside the folder and it still doesn't appear
(https://i.sstatic.net/mLtR9xWD.png)it looks like this
(enter image description here)but should be like this

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You should initialize your project with scarb init or if you want to using testing tool snforge init. After that you can type code . to open visual studio in your current dir
